# button onclick render partial view multiple times with multiple clicks in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My website has a section name 'carosel'. In main view user can click a button and add a 'carosel' section to the view. If clicking times equal to the no of 'carosel' sections. This section has no limit and user can add many 'carosel' sections to the main view.

partial view

```
  <style>

  .middle-section{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .middle-section-area{
    position: absolute;
    left: 260px;
    top: 175px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    border: 2px hidden;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .middle-section-name{
    position: absolute;
    left: 660px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    border: 2px hidden;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .middle-section-edit{
    position: absolute;
    left:860px;
    top:85px;
  }

  .middle-section-edit img{
    width: 20px;
    margin: 5px;

  }
</style>


<div class="middle-section">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="middle-section-name">
      </div>

      <div class="middle-section-edit">
        <%= image_tag 'settings-logo.png'%>
      </div>

      <div class="middle-section-area" >
        <p>carosel</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'll try to render this partial view many times with onclick. appriciate any idea or a answer

Comment: and the rest of the code ? where is it ? javascript i mean. please make a working example of your problem "  Questions seeking debugging help ( why isn't this code working? ) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: I want to render that partial view in another view multiple times with multiple button clicks. that's the basic idea. If you have any idea to done this task

Comment: well. have you tried something to accomplish what you are after ? if yes, post the code here ( javascript/jquery etc, )

Comment: I'll done this in another way. I hide this div section many times in the main view and write jquery to show that div sections. It's work for me but it's not a good standard way. Then i heard that partial rendering but i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll done it with, rails nested attributes add dynamically fields concept. That's the key idea.[check this it'd helpful](https://hackhands.com/building-has_many-model-relationship-form-cocoon/)